# SQL Group By and Join based on a weird client table

Tags: sql, join, sum

I have 3 tables that I want to join together and group it to get client membership info. My code works for grouping the base table together but it breaks at the join part and I can't figure out why.

```
BASE TABLE : sales_detail 
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
|   order_date | transaction_id|   product_cost |  payment_type  |    country
+-------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------+
|   10/1     |   12345         |      20       |      mastercard |    usa
|   10/1     |   12345         |      50       |      mastercard |    usa
|   10/5     |  82456          |      50       |      mastercard |    usa
|   10/9     |  64789          |      30       |      visa       |    canada
|   10/15    |  08546          |      20       |      mastercard |    usa
|   10/15    |  08546          |      90       |      mastercard |    usa
|   10/17    |  65898          |       50      |      mastercard |   usa
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

```
table : client_information
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   other_id    | client_Type       |   item  
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|   112341        |   new        | hola        |
|   112341        |   old        | mango       |
|   145634       |   old         | pine        | 
|   879547       |   old         | vip         |
|   745688       |   new         | unio        |  
|   745688       |   old         | dog         |
|   147899       |   new         | cat         |
|   124589        |   new        | amigo         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

```
table : connector
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   transaction_ID | other_id    |   item  
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|   12345        |   112341       | hola      |
|   82456        |   145634       | pine      | 
|   08157        |   879547       | unio      |
|   08546        |   745688       | dog       |  
|   65898        |   147899       | cat       |
|   06587        |   124589       | amigo     |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

**I want the output to look something like this: **

```
IDEAL OUTPUT
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------+
|   order_date | transaction_ID |   product_cost |  client_Type|   
+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------+
|   10/1     |   12345         |      70       |      new        |  
|   10/5     |   82456         |      70       |      old        |
|   10/15    |   08546         |      110      |      old        |
|   10/17    |   65898         |      50       |      new        |
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------+
```

**i am trying to join my base table to the connector table by transaction ID to get other_id and items to match to client_type  **

This is the code i used but it failed to compile after adding in left joins :

```
select t1.transaction_id, sum(t1.product_cost), t1.order_date, t3.client_type
from sales_detail t1
left join (select DISTINCT  transaction_ID, other_id, fruits from connector) t2
ON t1.transaction_ID=t2.transaction_ID
left join (select DISTINCT order_id, client_type, fruits from client information) t3 
ON t2.other_id=t3.other_id and t2.item=t3.item
where t1.payment_type='mastercard' and t1.order_Date between '2020-10-01' and'2020-10-31'
and country != 'canada'
GROUP BY t1.transaction_id, t1.order_date, t3.client_type;
```

Thanks in advance! I am a beginner so still learning the ins and outs of sql! (am using hive)

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's joins and aggregation. For more efficiency, you can pre-aggregate in a subquery, then join:

```
select sd.*, ci.client_type
from (
    select order_date, transaction_id, sum(product_cost) product_cost
    from sales_detail
    where 
        payment_type   =  'mastercard' 
        and order_date >= '2020-10-01' 
        and order_date <  '2020-11-01'
        and country    <>  'canada'
    group by order_date, transaction_id
) sd
inner join connector c on c.transaction_id = sd.transaction_id
inner join client_information ci on ci.other_id = c.other_id
```

Note that I rewrote the filter on `order_date` to use half-open intervals rather than `between`. This properly handles the case when your dates have a time portion.

Comment: thank you this works! question though, this works perfectly on sql fiddle, but for the real data, the run time is extremely slow. Is there a good way that you recommend that can speed up the query?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, your code works although not as you would like using an `INNER JOIN` and it fails to add a `LEFT JOIN`. I think what happens is a failure due to the `NULL` elements. to add a `NULL`  element and not get an error, you have to use some function that changes the `NULL`  value to `0` .

One such function is the `ISNULL(yourColumn, 0)` function of **T-SQL**.[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

I can see that in result table you only need clients **who used mastercard**, so you should **use inner join** there so only those client who used mastercard will be considered. While the remaining query is okay i guess, but main problem was the join on client information.

Answer (score 0):

I think on the answer with GMB you also need to join on item column otherwise you will get multiple rows output.

```
select sd.*, ci.client_type
from (
    select order_date, transaction_id, sum(product_cost) product_cost
    from sales_detail
    group by order_date, transaction_id
) sd
inner join connector c on c.transaction_id = sd.transaction_id
inner join client_information ci on ci.other_id = c.other_id and ci.item = c.item
```

Just modify with your filters and you should be sorted.

Comment: thank you this works! question though, this works perfectly on sql fiddle, but for the real data, the run time is extremely slow. Is there a good way that you recommend that can speed up the query?

Comment: As I have no idea what your schema looks like and how much data there is and other details I can't provide any guess as to how to do that.

Please mark the answer as appropriate and ask another question.